# Windows Phone 8 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll not recognized?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am a newbie to Windows Phone 8 app programming in C# and I am trying to create an array of textboxes. I have the array being created and being added as children of a Stack Panel, and I am trying to get it to display more than a few textboxes, and I read that it can be done if the CanContentScroll property is set to 'true' as it is set to 'false' by default. However, when I try to add it, it is not recognised by intellisense. Can you help me?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Margin="10,135,10,7" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="TextBoxStack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="419" Margin="0,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am using VS2013, and the System.Phone.Controls and System.Windows.Controls modules are included correctly.

Comment: Wait ... what is the problem exactly?  Is it just that the content is not scrolling?  Or is that that the scrolling is going by physical rather than logical units?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid and not a StackPanel. I forget the exact reason, but the StackPanel doesn't correctly report it size to the ScrollViewer container causing the ScrollViewer to not scroll correctly. Using a Grid will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set "CanContentScroll".  The `ScrollViewer` should display scroll bars if its child extends further than the ScrollViewer's bounds.  Try:

- Remove the fixed height of the child StackPanel.  You don't want to restrict its height -- it should extend as far as its children, so that the ScrollViewer knows the correct scroll extent.
- Make sure the ScrollViewer has a fixed or limited height -- ie, put it inside a fixed-size container like Grid, rather than an infinitely-extendable one like StackPanel.  If it can extend infinitely, it will always be able to accommodate its child, and won't ever think it has to scroll.

Eg:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel x:Name="TextBoxStack"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```